# Calculating the distance between two functions in $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $C([0,1])$ denote the real linear space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. We define the function $d:C([0,1])\times C([0,1])\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $$d(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)|\ dx.$$

I already proved that $d$ is a well-defined function and that $d$ gives a metric on $C([0,1])$.
Now, I want to calculate $d(f,g)$, for $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ and $g(x)=\cos(2\pi x)$. I started with making a little sketch, but I have no clue how this helps me and how to calculate this. Does anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the function $$h(x) = \vert f(x) - g(x) \vert$$
Now, let's see when $h(x) > 0$ and when $h(x) < 0$. First let's equate it to zero:
$$ f(x) - g(x) = 0 $$
so $$\cos(2 \pi x) = \sin(2 \pi x)$$ or $$\cos^2(2 \pi x) = \sin^2(2 \pi x)$$ which is 
$$1 - \sin^2(2 \pi x) = \sin^2(2 \pi x)$$
i.e.
$$\sin^2(2 \pi x) = \frac{1}{2}$$
which gives
$$\sin(2 \pi x) = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$, which means 
$$2 \pi x =  \sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) + k \pi$$ or 
$$ x =  \frac{1}{2 \pi} \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{k}{2} $$
finally we get that $h(x) = 0$ for the following values of $x$
$$x = \frac{1}{8} +  \frac{k}{2}$$
We only need these values for $0 < x < 1$, i.e. $$x_1 = \frac{1}{8} = 0.125$$ and $$x_2 = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{2} = 0.625$$. Now, we can compute the integral. Also, we can easily verify that $h(x) < 0$ when $x_1 < x< x_2$ and positive otherwise in $[0,1]$.

$$\int\limits_0^1 \vert h(x) \vert = \int\limits_0^{x_1} h(x) -  \int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2} h(x) +  \int\limits_{x_2}^{1} h(x)$$
The indefinite integral $\int h(x) = \int \sin(2 \pi x) - \cos(2 \pi x) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi}(\cos(2 \pi x) + \sin(2 \pi x))$, so the integral becomes
$$\int\limits_0^1 \vert h(x) \vert = -\frac{1}{2 \pi}(\cos(2 \pi x) + \sin(2 \pi x)) \Big\vert_{0}^{x_1} + \frac{1}{2 \pi}(\cos(2 \pi x) + \sin(2 \pi x)) \Big\vert_{x_1}^{x_2} -\frac{1}{2 \pi}(\cos(2 \pi x) + \sin(2 \pi x)) \Big\vert_{x_2}^{1}$$
I believe you can continue the calculation from the last equation.